# Why do I get very different behaviours from JComboBox, depending on platform (Windows/Linux) and language (Java/Jython)

Tags: java, linux, swing, cross-platform, jython

I'm writing a Jython application that will ultimately run on Linux. I develop on a Windows machine, and I'm getting inconsistent behaviour when I test on Linux.

- Dev machine- Windows XP, Java 6, Jython 2.5.2
- Test machine- Red Hat 3.4.3, Java 6, Jython 2.5.2

In Windows, using either Java or Jython, I get what I would consider to be 'normal' JComboBox behavior:

1. Click on the text or arrow, the list drops down.
2. Click on the desired item, the selection is made.

On Linux, I get the following behaviour from Java:

1. Click **and hold**, the list drops down.
2. Release on the desired item, the selection is made.
3. I also get some really bizarre behaviour, like

   - the ComboBox itself is rendered in the window where it should be, but I click and the list drops down from the top-left of the screen, or
   - the list is rendered in the right place when I click and hold, but I then have to drag the mouse to the top left to make the selection, as if the list is still dropping down from there.
4. The only way to make a selection is with the up/down arrow keys, and even with this I still get the list dropping down from (0, 0).

On Linux, I get the following behaviour from Jython:

1. Click **and hold**, the list drops down.
2. As I move the mouse downwards, the list items are highlighted, but they're off by about 1.5 lines. I.e, the second item isn't highlighted until the mouse is halfway down the third item.
3. Release the mouse button, and the list disappears as it should, but the original item is still selected, as if nothing happened.
4. Again, the only way to use the ComboBox properly is with the keyboard, although I don't get the same weirdness with the list dropping down from the wrong place.

Here is my Java SSCCE:

```
package foo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Foo extends JPanel{
    public Foo(){
        super(new BorderLayout());

        String[] contents = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz"};
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(contents);

        add(combo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    private static void BuildAndShow(){
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("Testing");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent contentPane = new Foo();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        mainWindow.setContentPane(contentPane);

        //Display the window.
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BuildAndShow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my Jython SSCCE:

```
from java.lang import Runnable
from javax.swing import SwingUtilities, JFrame, JComboBox
from java.awt import BorderLayout
import time

class Foo(Runnable):    
    def run(self):
        mainWindow = JFrame('Test', defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        mainWindow.setLayout(BorderLayout())
        mainWindow.add(JComboBox(["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]), BorderLayout.PAGE_START)
        mainWindow.visible = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Foo()
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(app)
    while True: 
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Works as expected on Mac OS X 10.5 and Ubuntu 10.04.3.

Comment: I should mention that my Linux testing is being done through SSH, using Xming, still sitting at the same Windows machine. I'm working on finding out where in this multi-storey office the Linux box is, so I can go sit at it and test.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Whoops, made some edits to the code, and missed that line. Try now.

Comment: OK it compiles for me now.  Unfortunately I trashed my Ubuntu OS the other week when installing Win 7 64 bit, and have not had time to reinstall it yet.

Comment: What is the JRE installed on Linux ? Ensure you are using the Oracle/Sun JRE, or OpenJDK 6. Avoid GCJ.

Comment: I'm using the the Oracle JRE. I have reason to believe that the SSH+XMing is what is causing the problem, but have yet to confirm. Should be able to get access to the machine in the next few hours and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finally actually getting physical access to the Linux machine I had been testing on remotely, everything worked fine.

So it turns out the problem was something to do with the combination of SSH, XMing, and whatever was set up to do the display forwarding on the Linux machine.

Apologies to anyone who spent time on what turned out to be an unanswerable question!